# Rails before_update not triggering on update but save works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Model looks like

```rb
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :delete_triggers

  def delete_triggers
    Trigger.where(campaign_id: id).delete_all
  end
end
```

and in the controller I do

```rb
Campaign.find(params[:campaignId]).update(campaign_params)
```

where `campaign_params` just grabs the body and does some cleanup. `delete_triggers` never gets called though. There is no filter (there will be, but I removed it since the method wasn't firing. It didn't make a difference). In order to sanity check, I added to the model

```rb
before_save :check_dirty

def check_dirty
  pp changed?
end
```

which prints `true` as expected.

What would cause `before_update` to not trigger on a call to `.update`, where `before_save` does? Obviously, I could just use `before_save` and add some filtering logic in the callback, but that's hacky when there's a hook made for this purpose.

(There are other questions similar to this, but not the same. One has a syntax error in a proc, and I'm not using a proc; and the other is a bad filter, which I removed specifically to avoid that possibility and am still getting the issue)

Comment: `before_update` is run after running validations. When the validation fails, then the following callbacks are not run. Is it possible that a validation failed?

Comment: @dbugger We do have a more explicit API param convention. That couldn't have been the problem though because then `check_dirty` wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @spickermann THANK YOU! If you make that an answer, I'll accept. I thought (apparently incorrectly), that `before_save` would've also been skipped if that was the case, so had disregarded that possibility. Guess I'll have to review AR callback order of ops.

Comment: @JessTheWitch I am not certain how `before_save` fires if validation fails as it does not appear this should be the case according to the [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). If validation fails then the last callback should be `after_validation`

Comment: @engineersmnky I agree that's what the docs say, but I don't know what to tell you. After commenting out the validator, the hook started running. Following that lead, I found that the rspec test this was running in was generating invalid values for Campaign's `description` (the hook not running had been causing the test clean up to fail from an fkey violation, and the stuff left behind meant `description` wasn't unique). Fixed that (and added back in the validator), and everything is peachy now.